# PHP Which Join Statement to use when trying to grab data from another table

Tags: php, join

I'm trying to figure out the best approach, more specifically which JOIN to use, with my current situation:

I have two tables (entries, users) in my database. I'm querying and displaying all my news entries on one of my pages. With each entry, I'm also posting the entry information such as date, time and the author (or user) who created the entry.

In my "entries" table, I'm only inputting the user's id (user_id) as the post's author. The "users" table has all the author's information, such as name, email, etc.

Which "JOIN" statement would be best for specifically querying the "entries" table to display all my entries but to also grab certain information from my "users" table just by matching the user_id from "entries" to user_id in "users"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple join statment

```
SELECT e.*,u.* FROM entries e JOIN users u
ON e.user_id = u.user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT INNER JOIN probably.

it will display all from entries, and if users is atached to entries will be dispplayed aswell, else the field will be null.